# How to count the quantity of items in Unordered List. JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to the StackOverflow community!
I've been searching for this topic and in some of them said that I can know what I'm looking for with .length but I cannot make it happen.

I'm also new in JQuery and JS, if anything in my code is messy I apologize.

My code:

```
$('#btnComments').click(function () {
    if ($('#commentArea').val() != "") {
        var $newli = document.createElement('li');
        $newli.textContent = $('#commentArea').val();
        $('#listaDeComentarios').after($newli);
        $('#commentArea').val('');
        var cantLiEnUl = $('#listaDeComentarios').length;
        $newli.tagName = 'Comments[' + cantLiEnUl.toString() + ']';
    }
});
```

In the first part of my code I'm just getting the text from a TextArea and add it to a Comment List. What I'm trying to do is to set the proper index to the name of the li because I'm posting that list with a model, and if I don't give each li an index then this property in the model reaches with null value.

I've been doing some console.log(cantLiEnUl) to know how was changing the value and it didn't, it always was 1. #listaDeComentarios is the id of my ul.

If anything isn't clear enough I'll be trying to explain myself better.

Thanks in advance!

I've found after I read the comment about @Turnip.

I'm posting it because he replied to a comment and cannot mark it as the solution. My problem was the .after

*You should be using .append instead of .after else the length will always be zero. You aren't actually adding the li to the ul. Also, you can't assign value to tagName - this is the 'type' of the element. In your case $newli.tagName equals 'LI'*

Thanks!

Comment: What does this question have to do with ```C#```?

Comment: Use the `length` property, eg `$('ul li').length`. If that isn't working for you, we would need to see a little more of your code. A working example would be great, or a sample of your HTML at least

Comment: You should be using `.append` instead of `.after` else the length will always be zero. You aren't actually adding the `li` to the `ul`. Also, you can't assign value to `tagName` - this is the 'type' of the element. In your case `$newli.tagName` equals 'LI'.

Comment: @Jules I'm doing it with ASP.NET MVC 5. If it isn't appropiate I can remove it. I apologize

Comment: @Turnip my problem was all about the .after! Thank you! I edited the post with your reply because I cannot mark your comment as the correct reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess and assume that you are trying to do something like this:

```js
$('#btnComments').click(function () {
    if ($('#commentArea').val() != "") {
        var $newli = document.createElement('li');
        $newli.textContent = $('#commentArea').val();

        /**
        * Use `.append` not `.after`...
        */
        $('#listaDeComentarios').append($newli);
        $('#commentArea').val('');
      
        /**
        * Check the length of the `li` not the `ul`...
        */
        var cantLiEnUl = $('#listaDeComentarios li').length;
        
        /**
        * Replace 'data-myData' with whatever attribute you are wanting to set...
        */
        $($newli).attr('data-myData', 'Comments[' + cantLiEnUl.toString() + ']');
    }
});
```

```css
#listaDeComentarios li:after {
  content: ' - ' attr(data-myData);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="commentArea" placeholder="Enter some text..."></textarea>
<br>
<button id="btnComments">
Click
</button>

<ul id="listaDeComentarios">

</ul>
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you!